# Visual Studio Code 'File' Menu appearing outside the screen on left side- how to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When running VS Code today, I noticed that the 'file' dropdown menu appears to the left instead of the right, like all the other dropdown menus. This might be a bug associated with the new release I recently downloaded, or just a problem I have personally, I don't know. Anyway, it's really annoying and I was wondering if anyone knows the specific VS Code setting that can help me fix this?

[image: GIF showing problem]

-- To clarify, in the GIF I have the IDE where it is in order to show the problem. Even when it's fullscreen the menu still appears to the left, which is to say off the screen!

I've tried looking at the VS Code settings related to "window" but I can't see anything that specifically deals with this issue. Either that or I don't know what I'm looking at!

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: Version: 1.81.0
Commit: 6445d93c81ebe42c4cbd7a60712e0b17d9463e97
Date: 2023-08-02T12:36:11.334Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.112-19403-gb69e1c36e415

Answer (score 0):

This very same issue was raised at [File menu (menu bar) opens on the screen at the left #122820](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122820), where [it was classified as a KDE issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122820#issuecomment-831342547) (it was suggested there as a workaround to just set `window.titleBarStyle` to `"custom"`). The issue was reported upstream at [Bug 436548: App icon menus opens on the screen at the left of the current window](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436548), but that was closed as needing more info. I suggest you raise an issue ticket to the KDE maintainers again, this time providing as much information as you possibly can about how to reproduce the issue- for example, [whether you are using Wayland](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436548#c4), in which case you should check if it is the same issue as [QTBUG-85297](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85297).

Comment: Thanks @starball for the reply. I have tried what "sbatten" says on that Github thread (" As a workaround from our side, you can set window.titleBarStyle to custom.") and that has fixed the problem, although the visual appearance of the top menu section has changed. If I were to raise an issue ticket, where would you recommend I do it? As far as I can see from your links, there's 3 different places where to report the problem.

Comment: @gdwhittaker94 I edited the workaround into my answer post. as for where to report, do it in the KDE issue tracker. Make sure to provide the info that was asked for before in previous issue tickets but not provided.